# Iterating in a mathematical Sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, database, loops

I have this raw data set in a text file where each line is a new piece of data, I need to iterate through the file line by line and change the lines that are dates to a specific date format. Theses dates occur on lines 2, 7, 16, 23 etc

In order to do this I need to iterate over those specific lines so as not to corrupt the data that is on the other lines.
Would there be any way to iterate this way in python?

here is a screencap of the data..

[image]

You can see the lines i want manipulated can be found at lines 2, 9, 16, 23 etc 
The dates ranges are in the format of *Month/Day - Month/Day* in case ye have any difficulty finding.

And I will also include the raw text too
It can be found at this link
[Link to raw data](https://pastebin.com/y26sZzNP)

```
#my rough idea
infile = open("polling_Data.txt", "W+")
for line in infile: # specified range
     #code to edit date etc
```

Let me know if ye have any relevant solutions i know that maybe some form of regex may be suitable, open to all sorts of ideas thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really suggest writing in a new file and then delete the old file just in case anything went wrong along the way. You can do that using the following code:

```
import re

month_day_regex = r"(\d{,2}/\d{,2} - \d{,2}/\d{,2})"
new_data = []
# reading "polling_Data" text file
with open("polling_Data.txt", "r") as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if re.match(month_day_regex, line):
            new_data.append("##########") #do whatever you want
        else:
            new_data.append(line)
```

Now, the variable `new_data` has the same data as the text file with one change which is replacing the *Month/Day* entries with *#########* just to stand out. Now, let's write this variable into a new file:

```
with open("new_polling_data.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in new_data:
        outfile.write(line+'\n')
```

And here is a screenshot of the new file
[image]

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Try `\b\d\d?/\d\d?[ ]?-[ ]?\d\d?/\d\d?\b`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/xThEjS/1)